# Parse Push Stops Sending after IOS App minor Update

Tags: ios, parse-platform

We are having an issue with Parse Push.

For  the past three weeks, we have successfully used Parse Push to send out daily notifications about our blog.

However, on Wednesday, we submitted an update to our app (note - just a minor update to some styling and text within the app.) We updated the app from version 1.0 to version 1.0.1. It should also be noted this is a very basic app. It just has an RSS feed to pull content from the website..

Then on the following morning (Thursday), Parse stopped sending out notifications. We are using the  "Simple Parse Push Service" plug-in on our WordPress site to send the notifications to Parse and this is working because the notifications show up in the Parse dashboard, but Parse does not automatically send them out.

The only way that we can send out notifications now is by going into the dashboard and manually sending out notifications.

Answer (score -1):

Try going to your Data Browser in your Parse dashboard and see if the "appIdentifier" for that particular Installation has been changed somehow since your update. And if it is different you may need to update your app again with a redesign for when it sets the currentInstallation for the user.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked in the dashboard and the field for 'appldentifier' has not changed.  It looks the same on every instance of the app installation.  I apprecaite your help.

Comment: Ok Ill check back by time I get home if this is answered correctly yet, if not I may have an idea. But got to go now. Lates.